# Formbuilder RepeatedType PasswordType placeholder

Tags: forms, symfony, silex, formbuilder

I use the Symfony formbuilder to make Password field (PasswordType) of type repeat (RepeatedType):

```
->add('plainPassword', RepeatedType::class, [
    'type' => PasswordType::class,
    'required' => true,
    'first_options'  => array('label' => 'Password'),
    'second_options' => array('label' => 'Repeat Password'),
    'constraints' => [
        new Assert\NotBlank(['message' => "Ce champ est obligatoire."]),
        new Assert\Length([
            'min' => 8,
            'minMessage' => 'Le mot de passe doit comporter plus de {{ limit }} caractères.',
        ]),
    ],
    'invalid_message' => 'Le mot de passe doit être identique.',
    'options' => ['attr' => [
        'class' => 'password-field',
        'placeholder' => "Mot de passe"
    ]],
])
```

But I want to have 2 differents placeholder for the 2 passwords input, I don't know how to do that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can add `attr` attribute to `first_options` and `second_options`, e.g:

```
$builder
    ->add('password', RepeatedType::class, [
        'type' => PasswordType::class,
        'invalid_message' => 'The password fields must match.',
        'first_options' => ['label' => 'New password', 'attr' => ['placeholder' => 'First placeholder']],
        'second_options' => ['label' => 'Repeat new password', 'attr' => ['placeholder' => 'Second placeholder']],
        ...
    ])
```